# Application crash after taking a photo

Tags: android

I am using this code to create a simple camera apps. I can take a photo. However, the application crash after taking the photo.

```
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                       

    File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "abc.jpg");


    Uri store= Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, store);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

/***************************************onActivityResult***************************************/

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    if (imageFile.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "The file was saved at " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving the file ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                        break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Below is the logcat.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.camera/com.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.exists()' on a null object reference
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3758)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3801)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.exists()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.camera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:43)
>
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6463)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3754)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3801)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>    
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

I can't figure out why is this happening. Does anyone know how should I fixed the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Activity is recreated when the user navigates back from the Camera click action to the Activity.

Thus, you need to store the file path in the Bundle within `onSaveInstanceState()` (make sure to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` *after* calling `putString` on the `outState` `Bundle`), and create the File again within `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: I just started Android programming and not really sure how to use the functions illustrated in your solution on my application. How should I write the code you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: Basically, when you navigate away from an Activity, the Activity might get destroyed. And then when you navigate back to it, it gets recreated. Now what is happening in your question is that your `File` object is being nullified when the Activity is being recreated. Thus, to restore its previous state, you save the `File`'s identified (i.e. the file path) into the `Bundle` by overriding the `onSaveInstanceState()`, and then create a new instance of the `File` by overriding the `onRestoreInstanceState()`. The `Bundle`'s object has methods like `putString`, `putInt`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the appropriate permissions configured in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`

(`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and/or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)

Comment: I have both of it inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to retrieve the image URI from the `Intent` parameter:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    imageFile = new File(data.getData().toString());
                    if (imageFile.exists())
                    {
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I am still having the same problem. Do you know of other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you have two `imageFile` variables, one that you define and send in the intent, and another `imageFile` global variable that is always null.

This code works perfectly:

```
public class CameraIntentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private File imageFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_intent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "abc.jpg");

        Uri store= Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, store);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    if (imageFile.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "The file was saved at " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving the file ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```